# Is there any way I can use MySQL in python to persist data from Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Is there any way I can use MySQL in python to persist data from Pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can use sqlalchemy,

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', 
 echo=False)
df.to_sql(name='sample_table2', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

with pymysql connector

```
# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='root', db='test')
cursor = connection.cursor()
# connection is not autocommit by default. So we must commit to save our changes.
connection.commit()

engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/test"
                    .format(user="root",
                            pw="root",
                            db="test"))
df.to_sql(name='sample_table2', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

Comment: any other connectors do you recommend? @pyd

Comment: ANYWAY i USED pymysql connector.

Comment: I got into some work. sorry. I am updating pymysql connection part as well. please review

Comment: we dont need to import pymysql, sqlalchemy will take care, pls test the code